# foursquare authorize url is not loading in android webview

Tags: foursquare

My login webview is not loading in android.But months ago it was fine.
 I also wrote a project for accessing foursquare from android.
 https://github.com/goutomroy/DroidSquare/blob/master/README.md
 When I am trying to load webview, I found message :
 "The connection to the server was unsuccessful"
 Where is my fault ?

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
private void setUpWebView() {

    String URL_LOGIN = "https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authenticate?"
            + "client_id="+ FoursquareConstants.CLIENT_ID 
            + "&response_type=code"
            + "&display=touch"
            + "&redirect_uri=" + FoursquareConstants.URL_CALLBACK;

    CookieSyncManager.createInstance(activity);
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    cookieManager.acceptCookie();
    cookieManager.removeAllCookie();

    webView = new WebView(getContext());
    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    settings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new FoursquareWebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl(URL_LOGIN);
    setContentView(webView);
}

 class FoursquareWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        Log.d("onReceivedError", errorCode +" : "+description+ " : " + failingUrl);
        super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);

        dismissProgressDialog();
        LoginDialog.this.dismiss();
        responseHandler.onError(description);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

        Log.d("onPageStarted", url);
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

        if(flag) 
            return;
        else if (url.startsWith(FoursquareConstants.URL_CALLBACK)) {
            flag = true;
            String urls[] = url.split("=");
            responseHandler.onSuccess(urls[1]);
            LoginDialog.this.dismiss();
            return;
        }

        else
            showOrUpdateProgressDialog("Loading...");

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        Log.d("onPageFinished", url);
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        dismissProgressDialog();
    }

     @Override
     public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
         Log.d("onReceivedSslError", "error");
         handler.proceed(); // Ignore SSL certificate errors
     }
}
```

Comment: Have you added `INTERNET` permission in your manifest file ?

Comment: @GrIsHu yes I have added the internet permission.

Answer (score 3):

You should check for the internet permission at manifest file

```
<manifest xlmns:android...>
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```